# Changing style of mui stepper icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I would like to change the color of the icon from [image]

to this : [image]

I know that it's not .Mui-active nor .Mui-completed , I tested .Mui-disabled but it doesn't work

here is the link to the sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalnonlinearstepper-demo-material-ui-forked-u2yt0e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Any help ?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time. See this [FAQ for more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/17493431)

Comment: Also, it seems that is this already solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was a bit tricky, I had to add quite a few styles to achieve that.

First I've given every icon a `round` and `visible` border. The second style object ensures that the icon color is white and it excludes `checked` icons since we want them to look like usual.

```
  ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
    borderRadius: "50%",
    border: "1px solid #1976d2"
  },
  ".MuiSvgIcon-root:not(.Mui-completed)": {
    color: "white"
  }
```

Next the text is being filled with the same `color` as the `border` and I made it more bold to be more readable.

```
  ".MuiStepIcon-text": {
    fill: "#1976d2",
    fontWeight: 500
  }
```

Last but not least the active icon should still remain the same so I've reduced the margin from `-4px` to `-3px` since the border adds `1px` in every direction. The check icon should remain white so thats styled with `fill: "white"`.

```
  ".MuiSvgIcon-root.Mui-active": {
    color: "#1976d2",
    padding: "3px",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    border: "1px solid #1976d2",
    marginY: "-3px"
  },
  ".Mui-active .MuiStepIcon-text": {
    fill: "white"
  }
```

And this is the result:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit HorizontalNonLinearStepper demo — Material UI (forked)]